# Android - Problem of WrapText in Edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am facing trouble to set WrapText kind of facility in EditText.

**Problem**: When i try tp enter data in EditText, it goes beyond the screen width (scrolling horizontally). Instead of it should be appear in next-line.

**Want to perform:** Actually, i want to implement multiline edittext, initially it should display with single-line as usual, but it will be expanded vertically(not horizontally) as when data is being entered.

**Please suggest me what should i do ??**

Please have a look at below image:

[image]

I have done the below XML coding:

```
<TableLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:stretchColumns="1">

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow02" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView 
            android:text="Name:" 
            android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
            android:layout_width="80dp" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16dip">
        </TextView>
        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/txtViewName" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textFilter|textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false">
        </EditText>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: pls check the update above: Want to perform:

Comment: @pm-paresh-mayani why not use in RelativeLayout,  i guess it will works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just change this:  **`android:layout_width ="0dip"`** and it is working fine.

Multiline edittext but initially it is being displayed one line, it will be expanded vertically(not horizontally) as and when the more and more data are being entered.

Comment: I got the hint/light in mind from this article: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.android.devel/107004

Answer (score 2):

You can try to change the `width` to `fill_parent.`

Comment: Not working, i have tried and having no success, while entering more text, edittext is scrolling horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

try adding following code in your edit text if you want to wrap it in a single line:

`android:singleLine="true"`

OR set the width of your edittext to fill_parent or any value in dip if you want multiline.

Comment: hey check this  android:inputType="textFilter|textMultiLine" in my question, then howz it is possible to set android:singleLine="true" , does it make any sense???

Answer (score 1):

Just use both `android:stretchColumns="1"` and `android:shrinkColumns="1"` instead the only one `android:stretchColumns="1"`:

```
<TableLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
    android:shrinkColumns="1">
```

Answer (score -2):

I've tested it on a 2.1 emulator enclosing the code (with fill_parent in the edit text) inside this relative layout and appears to be ok.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:stretchColumns="1">

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow02" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:text="Name:"
            android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16dip">
        </TextView>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtViewName"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:inputType="textFilter"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false">
        </EditText>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Maybe you can navigate the xml tree in the eclipse outline window and see what view is bigger than the screen.

Comment: -1 @Pedro Fraca: first read question carefully and then post answer. What exactly user want.

Comment: I changed the answer according to the question. I think this solution works as the author of the question needs.